# HornetQ local connection never timing out

Tags: jboss, message-queue, hornetq, ttl

My application, running in a JBOSS standalone env, relies on a HornetQ (v2.2.5.Final) middleware to exchange messages between parts of my application in a local environment - *not over the network*.

The default TTL (time-to-live) value for the connection is [60000ms](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#dead.connections), I am thinking of changing that to `-1` since, from an operative point of view, I am looking forward to keep sending messages through such connection from time to time (not known in advance). Also, that would prevent issues like [jms queue connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883982/jboss7-remote-mdb-connection-to-jms-queue-connection-failure-has-been-detected).

The question is: what are the issues with never timing out a connection on the server side, in such context? Is that a good choice? If not, is there a strategy that is suited for such situation?

Comment: What version of HornetQ are you using?  The latest versions automatically disable connection checking for in-vm connections.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am using v2.2.5.Final which dates 2011

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Are you trying to address a current issue or avoid an issue that you're worried about?

Comment: I am trying to address a current issue related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883982/jboss7-remote-mdb-connection-to-jms-queue-connection-failure-has-been-detected. What I am worried about is that something may break if I was to set ttl = -1 and rely on this connection to be open at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of HornetQ automatically disable connection checking for in-vm connections so there shouldn't be any issues if you configure this manually.

Comment: Agreed. Configuring it manually is an acceptable choice for in-vm connections. It prevents HQ from closing the connections for timeout and is not causing any issue with the application side. Tested on many hours monitored run.